# FreeBSD jail with ezjail fails to log in with non root users

Tags: freebsd, jail

I just installed a fresh new FreeBSD 10.1 (FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE-p9) and set up a jail with ezjail (ezjail-admin v3.3).

Inside the jail I created a new user:

```
Login: test
Password: *
Uid [#]: 1001
Gid [# or name]: 1001
Change [month day year]:
Expire [month day year]:
Class:
Home directory: /home/test
Shell: /bin/sh
```

Yet, as soon I try to log in I have this error:

```
root@myjail:~ # su -l test
su: /bin/sh: Permission denied
```

It's the first time I see this behavior. I searched for similar issues but I didn't found nothing similar. And I have no ideas on how to fix this.

Some hints?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have `/bin/sh` listed in the jail's `/etc/shells`? Try any shell listed there, probably `/bin/csh`.

Comment: @Kondybas yes. Content of /etc/shells:  `
/bin/sh
/bin/csh
/bin/tcsh`

Comment: and all the shells have owner `root:wheel` and permissions `-r-xr-xr-x`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is at the root filesystem: bin, sbin, lib and others basic folders are not readable by normal users. I had to fix them manually.

Full details here: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/freebsd-jail-with-ezjail-fails-to-log-in-with-non-root-users.51523/